# Text for button toggles

Tags: toggle

I am currently creating a Grasshopper 3D component that parses XML data from a particular URL. Taking into account UX principles, I have some questions in-regards to my wording.

[image]

The functionality of the parser involves:

1. A HUD that overlays contextual information onto the component.
2. Allows toggling between "Use Unix timestamp" and "Use readable date/time"

[image: Note: unix timestamp is a more-machine-readable data type while the readable date/time is the self-explanatory humanly-readable timestamp.]

3. A metric/U.S.Standard toggle.

My questions are: are there better ways to name my toggles? Is the language consistent?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that **the user is not aware of his options**. How does he know he can *switch to* Metric? Or similarly: how does he know he *is in* Metric?

In your second screenshot, it says "Use Metric". So in what unit is the user *right now*?

Considering that toggles have **2 mutually exclusive** options, you should display them **both**. It would:

- display the *current* state of the option
- display the possible *alternative* option

Quick mockup:

[image]

I used disabled buttons here but try to make them look as section titles.